# In comparison to axis=0, how does np.argmin(arr, axis=1) work on 2D and 3D arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I know how does `np.argmin(arr, axis=0)` work. But `np.argmin(arr, axis=1)` has confused me.

### Example 1:

**Code:**

```
a2 = np.array([[1. , 2. , 3.3],
               [4. , 5. , 6.5]])

np.argmin(a2, axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
array([0, 0], dtype=int64)
```

**Confusion:**

My point of confusion is, there are 2 indices, and 3 columns in total. Then why is it giving an output of (0,0)? It should give the following outputs instead:

**Expected Output # 1:**

```
array([0], dtype=int64)
```

**Reason:**
Because, it has found the lowest element in the "index 0".

**Expected Output # 2:**

```
array([0, 0, 0], dtype=int64)
```

**Reason:**
Because, after comparing the elements of index 0 elements with index 1. It should say that everytime I did comparison with the both indices, I found lowest element in index 0

### Example 2:

**Code:**

```
a5 = np.array([[[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
                [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
                [ 7,  8,  9, 10]],

               [[10, 11, 12, 13],
                [16, 17, 18, 19],
                [19, 20, 21, 22]]])

np.argmin(a5, axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

**Confusion:**
Now why is it giving me 4 columns and 2 rows in the output?

Comment: That's not the output you get, the output is `array([0, 0, 0], dtype=int64)` - you probably made a typo and went to SO before double-checking? Or is the typo in your question and are you asking about `np.argmin(a2, axis=1)` instead? `axis = 0` is going over the rows, so three results, one for each column. `axis = 1` is the opposite in a 2D array.

Comment: Nothing better than documentation if you are confused. It says `np.argmin` returns the indices of the minimum values along an axis. And `axis=1` is columns. Well, minimum values are 1 and 4, both have zero indices, so the output is `[0, 0]`. I think you should be very careful while trying to understand these descriptive sentences in numpy docs.

Comment: Yes, I did double-check my code and everything. The output I am getting is the same as in my question. In fact, let me update my question with another example of another array, which is doing the same thing.

Comment: @mathfux you are always there to rescue me man. Let me update my question with another example in it, so that you can better understand what is confusing me.

Comment: @mathfux I have updated my question with Example 1 and Example 2.

Comment: @Grismar you were right. I made an error in my question here. It should have been np.argmin(a2, axis=1). I have rectified it.

Comment: @Web Development Labs seems that your issue is rather a psilosophical one. It can be formulated as "Which developmental tools should I use to understand mathematical objects and their notations". It's a different cathegory, out of competencies of the majority SO users but I'll try to give you some clues about it and answer it, so just wait for an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that I can't get these notations fully as well because I always catch myself confussing last axis with before last one:

#### 2D model (row-column)

[image]

Unfortunately, results of `np.argmin` for different axis are:

```
np.argmin(arr, axis=0)    np.argmin(arr, axis=1) 
       [0 0 1]                    [0 2]
```

#### 3D model (level-row-column)

[image]

This is close too:

```
np.argmin(arr, axis=0)    np.argmin(arr, axis=1)    np.argmin(arr, axis=2) 
       [0 0]                      [0 1]                       [0 1]
       [1 0]                      [1 1]                       [0 0]
```

And again, this works pretty well except that `axis=1` is swapped with `axis=2`.

I don't know where this magic swap comes from but hope this imagery helps for OP to understand how axis are linked with dimensions.

It would be nice if anyone could comment why do I need to extraordinaly apply a rule `Swap last two axes of your expected output`.

Comment: what a great presentation and explanation. I loved it. You are right. This is the same way I have observed and memorized it while you were busy in making this :-) but I would love to keep this with me as in good source and reference. Because, mine is all in text form and on Jupyter lol.

Comment: This is mostly the old Mister Paint. Unfortunately, no script examples for inception of these diagrams. A second diagram was made with [`LaTeX (tikz)`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12021/132818) + `Paint`. I also agree that `numpy` lacks visualisations to understand it and you need to draw it paper-based unless it's not possible to make it in your mind.

Comment: thank you so much for everything man! you are right about lacking of numpy visualizations that can be found on internet. I also first made it on a paper and then made some text based visualisations on my Jupyter notebook lol.

Comment: @Web Development Labs I spent some time while implementing such kind of visualisations. An example we were discussing is a part of my [larger project](https://github.com/loijord/numpyviz) (namely Example 6), you're welcome to see and use it.

Comment: I will definitely have a look over that. Btw bud. How can I get in touch with you directly over email, Whatsapp or any other medium?

Comment: @Web Development Labs check my email, this is given at Github

Answer (score 2):

The handling of `np.min` and `argmin` is the same, regardless of the axis number.  0 doesn't mean anything more special than 1 or 2.  In all cases, the named axis is removed from the result (same for `np.sum`).

Let's make something more random and more interesting:

```
In [216]: arr = np.arange(24)
In [218]: np.random.shuffle(arr)
In [219]: arr
Out[219]: 
array([10,  2, 12, 11, 15,  8, 17, 20, 13, 21, 14,  1, 22,  7,  3,  5,  9,
        0, 19, 16, 18,  6, 23,  4])
In [220]: arr = arr.reshape(2,3,4)
In [221]: arr
Out[221]: 
array([[[10,  2, 12, 11],
        [15,  8, 17, 20],
        [13, 21, 14,  1]],

       [[22,  7,  3,  5],
        [ 9,  0, 19, 16],
        [18,  6, 23,  4]]])
```

With `axis=0`, identify which 'plane' has the minimum value, for each 'row/col' element.

```
In [222]: np.min(arr, axis=0)
Out[222]: 
array([[10,  2,  3,  5],
       [ 9,  0, 17, 16],
       [13,  6, 14,  1]])
In [223]: np.argmin(arr, axis=0)
Out[223]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

`argmin` values are value index values for a dimension of size 2.  The `10` is in the first plane, the `3` in the second, and so forth.

Doing the same thing with axis 2 (rows):

```
In [224]: np.min(arr, axis=2)
Out[224]: 
array([[2, 8, 1],
       [3, 0, 4]])
In [225]: np.argmin(arr, axis=2)
Out[225]: 
array([[1, 1, 3],
       [2, 1, 3]])
```

The `2` is in the second column, `1` in the fourth, etc.

Using that `argmin` to fetch the `min` values requires some familiarity with advanced indexing:

```
In [226]: arr[[[0],[1]], [0,1,2], _225]     # Out[225] argmin
Out[226]: 
array([[2, 8, 1],
       [3, 0, 4]])
```

Here I use (2,1) and (3,) arrays (or lists that can be made into arrays) that will broadcast together to match the (2,3) `argmin` index.  Together they pick a (2,3) array of values from the (2,3,4) shaped `arr`.

A newish function `take_along_axis` is supposed to make application of `argmin` easier.  It has an example.  Applied here:

```
In [236]: idx = _225    
In [237]: np.take_along_axis(arr, idx[...,None], axis=2)
Out[237]: 
array([[[2],
        [8],
        [1]],

       [[3],
        [0],
        [4]]])
```

This is the `Out[224]` `np.min` array expanded to 3d (2,3,1) shape.  It may be easier to pick out minimum elements in the `Out[221]` display.

```
In [238]: idx[...,None]
Out[238]: 
array([[[1],
        [1],
        [3]],

       [[2],
        [1],
        [3]]])
```

Comment: thank you so much for your precious time. I really appreciate that. Your explanation has been very helpful for me in making my notes. I would keep this as well handy as reference :-)